# I'm trying to integrate AWS Cognito with Azure Ad for single sign on, but the page login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf is throwing a 404 error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, saml-2.0

When trying to login via my AWS Cognito's login page via Azure AD with email@live.com credentials, I'm being redirected to `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?response_type=code&client_id=51483342-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxx...` and the page is throwing a 404 error.

Steps:

- Created an Azure AD Enterprise Non Gallery Application.
- Added identifier to enterprise application: `urn:amazon:cognito:sp:ap-southeast-1_xxxxx`
- Added reply url as: `https://xxxxx.auth.ap-southeast-1.amazoncognito.com/saml2/idpresponse`
- Downloaded the SAML Signing Certificate > Federation Metadata XML and uploaded it on Cognito by adding a new SAML identity provider.
- Mapped SAML attribute `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress` to `Email` under Cognito Attribute Mapping.
- Enabled the AzureAd identity provider under App Client Settings on Cognito.
- Allowed OAuth Flows: Authorization code grant, Implicit grant.
- Invited an existing `xxx@live.com` user to Azure Active Directory and assigned a role to the user in the newly created Enterprise application.
- Validated SSO from Enterprise Application > SSO > Validate. It's working as correctly, without any errors.

Problem:

- When trying to login via [Cognito's login url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/login-endpoint.html): `https://xxxxx.auth.ap-southeast-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=token&client_id=Cognito-App-Client-ID&redirect_uri=Callback-url-specified-in-cognito-app-client-settings` --> AzureAd, I'm being redirected to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/...` where I enter the added user's email Id: `xxx@live.com`, after clicking next, instead of a password prompt the page throws a 404 error.
- Also tried with inviting another user with email: `xxx@mydomain.com`, this also results in the same 404 error.
- Tried in different browsers: chrome, firefox, safari. All result in the exact same error.

Comment: Is the 404 coming from the MS login page or AWS or something else? Could you check from F12 tools what URL returns the 404?

Comment: It's coming from MS login page. In incognito, when I enter the email, I'm never prompted for a password but the page returns 404. I think, it's a part of MS login process and this page was supposed to show me a password prompt, but due to some unidentifiable issue it throws a 404. 
[Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/CTRlxlj.jpg)

Comment: Oh... That looks bad 

Comment: For me the MS login works in an Incognito window though. Not sure what would cause this :\

Comment: This may be fixed now. I have just finished setting up AWS SSO with Azure AD, and after some config changes(AWS wasn't accepting the default SAML mapping) I managed to get guest user login working.

Comment: as RyuzakiLost said, SSO with personal account still seems to have some problem. once I have logged in portal.azure.com with my personal account, redirect to login.live.com have no problem, otherwise (after signed out from portal.azure.com), login.live.com returns 404 and SSO flow stalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure AD SSO SAML2.0 integration doesn't work well with personal accounts.
Integrating with OIDC on the other hand works really well.

[Azure AD integration with AWS Cognito.](https://www.terminalbytes.com/azure-ad-integration-as-an-idp-with-aws-cognito/)